# binding list element onclick event to radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a jquery function or some easy way by id to bind whatever happens when you select a radio button to a `<li>` onclick event?
example code:

```
<li onclick="showInfo();" //bind to radio here somehow>
   <div class="radioHolder">
       <input name="blah" type="radio" id="asdf" checked="false"/>
   </div>
   <label for="asdf">blahblah</label>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean, can you be more specific?

Comment: So you want the radio button to change when the list item is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Used with no parameters the click method fires the click event (if that's what you need)

```
$('li').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

When li is clicked, trigger the click of asdf

```
$('li').click(function(event)
{
  $('asdf').click()
});
```